# How would i bulk this?

Tags: apex, field-update, bulkification

```
List<Account> acctList = [SELECT Id FROM Account Where  Guest_Type__c = NULL LIMIT 100];

for(Account acct :acctList){
    acct.Guest_Type__C = 'Conference';
    acct.Segment_1__C = '24 Hour Week Day';
}

update acctList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to explore the apex batch interface:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

Their are some examples in the above link that are very similar to what you will need to do. Let us know if you have any questions.